# Mapping object's related entities by other field than ID

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, modelmapper

I am using the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Book> books;
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

and the following DTO:

```
public class NewBookRequest {
    private UUID userUuid;
}
```

and the converter:

```
@Component
public class NewBookRequestToEntityConverter implements Converter<NewBookRequest, Book> {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public NewBookRequestToEntityConverter(final ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Book convert(@NotNull final NewBookRequest source) {
        return modelMapper.map(source, Book.class);
    }
}
```

and there is part of service code:

```
public void addBook(final NewBookRequest newBookRequest) {
    final Book newBook = newBookRequestToEntityConverter.convert(newBookRequest);
    bookRepository.save(newBook);
}
```

When I try to save the converted Book entity I get the ConstraintViolationException exception, as `newBook.user.id` is null. However, newBook.user.uuid is correctly assigned. Is there any way to automatically map newBook's user by its uuid? Or the only solution is to do something like this:

add new method to converter:

```
@Component
public class NewBookRequestToEntityConverter implements Converter<NewBookRequest, Book> {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public NewBookRequestToEntityConverter(final ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Book convert(@NotNull final NewBookRequest source) {
        return modelMapper.map(source, Book.class);
    }

    public Book convert(@NotNull final NewBookRequest source, final User user) {
        Book target = modelMapper.map(source, Book.class);
        target.setUser(user);
        return target;
    }
}
```

and modify service's code:

```
public void addBook(final NewBookRequest newBookRequest) {
    final User user = userRepository.getUserByUuid(newBookRequest.getUserUuid());
    final Book newBook = newBookRequestToEntityConverter.convert(newBookRequest, user);
    bookRepository.save(newBook);
}
```

? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I love when someone gives -1 to your post and gives no explanation

Answer (score 1):

In Book or User entity you could use UUID as primary key. Did you try that?

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "UUID",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;
```

However on some databases there can be performance issue when using indexes based on UUID if there is high load.

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to use UUID as a primary key. UUID is used alongside with ID

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is your converter does not initialize the primary key of `User`.
You may either change the type of `id` field in the `User` class due to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64141178/14225495, or add the annotation

```
@JoinColumn(name = "user_uuid", referencedColumnName = "uuid")
```

to the `user` field in the `Book` class. In this case you should also add column `"user_uuid"` in the `books` table, make sure the `users.uuid` column is unique and not nullable to create foreign key.

Comment: But the thing is that UUID is used alongside with ID...

Comment: You need one column for the association. This column must be specified in the `@JoinColumn` and this column should be a foreign key. You may choice either `id` or `uuid`.

Comment: Due to you receive the user uuid from the client I would recommend to use the `uuid`.